# 'I know what is good and what is bad'

Tags: clauses

1. 'I know what is good.'
2. 'I know who is good.'

Here 'What is good' and 'who is good' must be noun clauses.therefore I think we can use these noun clauses as subject, e.g.

1. What is good is learning English.
2. Who is clever at mathematics must be John.

Are these sentences (grammatically) correct? and can we use clauses which start with 'who' as subject of verb?

1. Who is clever at mathematics must be John.
2. Who designed this building ought to be shot.

Or must these clauses be changed to, for instance:

1. The man who is clever at...............
2. The person who designed this building........   ?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is ingenious, but unfortunately doesn't work: language isn't always as logical as we might like to think.

First, you're right that *who is good* can be a noun phrase, but it doesn't follow that it can necessarily be used as the subject or a verb. In fact, for reasons that are not clear to me, *what is good* and *whoever is good* are grammatical as subject, but *who is good* is borderline, and I think ungrammatical.

This is all confounded by another problem, which is that these phrases have several possible meanings, which are differently selected by the grammatical context.

So *what is good* as a clause can mean:

1. the answer to the question "What is good?"
2. something that is good
3. everything that is good
4. which things are good

As the object of *I know*, it generally means 1 or 4 (perhaps 3). But as the subject of a verb it usually means 2 (perhaps 3).

So

> I know what is good.

and

> What is good is swimming in the sea.

Are both reasonable things to say; but they do not imply, or have anything to do with the barely comprehensible:

> ?I know swimming in the sea

Comment: thank you for your reply!

    Can you tell me what clause can be used as subject of verb?

    1.Who is clever at mathematics(is john.) or
    2.The man who is clever at mathematics (is john.)

Comment: As I said a clause like _who is ..._ can never, I think, be used the subject. _The person who is ..._ or _the man who is ..._ is fine.